# Why Marshal.SizeOf<>() is giving different size for struct or class?

Tags: c#, marshalling

I'm testing some code, and I realized that Marshal.SizeOf gives a different size for class or struct. I don't understand why.

I tried to change the "Pack" and the return value of method SizeOf didn't changed.

Here is the code:

```
Console.WriteLine(Marshal.SizeOf<SSItem1>().ToString()); //Gives 26
Console.WriteLine(Marshal.SizeOf<SSItem2>().ToString()); //Gives 8

//CLASS
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
    public class SSItem1
    {
        public short ItemId;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 3)]
        public SSItemEF1[] Ef;  // 2 a 7    = 6
    }
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
    public class SSItemEF1
    {
        public byte Type;   // 0
        public byte Value;  // 1
    }

//STRUCT
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
    public struct SSItem2
    {
        public short ItemId;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 3)]
        public SSItemEF2[] Ef;  // 2 a 7    = 6
    }
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
    public struct SSItemEF2
    {
        public byte Type;   // 0
        public byte Value;  // 1
    }
```

## Obs: The code is being run in x64 mode.

Comment: You ought to mention that you run this code in 64-bit mode.  Unlike an array of structs, an array of objects gets marshaled as an array of pointers to the marshaled objects.  So the comment for SSItemEF1 is wrong, since it stores 3 pointers it takes 3 * 8 bytes of storage.  You almost surely meant to make SSItemEF1 a struct since that's the only sensible way to declare a ByValArray.

Comment: Oh boy :v. Thank you, now I understand it a little more.